# Generating multiple OpenAPI documents with NSwag

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, openapi, nswag, .net-6.0

I have a set of APIs that's available under `/api/v1/` route, and a set of internal APIs (stuff that makes the admin panel tick and such) under `/admin/api/v1/` route. I currently have NSwag with OpenAPI documents and SwaggerUI3 implemented, but it contains **all** routes.

After a couple of hours of googling, cursing, and I'm pretty sure getting a mild aneurysm, I managed to scavenge what precious few bits and pieces of information exist and cobble together this bit of code:

```cs
// OpenAPI
app.UseOpenApi();
app.UseSwaggerUi3(settings =>
{
    settings.Path = "/swagger";
});
// OpenAPI Internal
app.UseOpenApi(settings =>
{
    settings.Path = settings.Path.Replace("swagger", "swagger-internal");
});
app.UseSwaggerUi3(settings =>
{
    settings.Path = "/swagger-internal";
    settings.DocumentPath = settings.DocumentPath.Replace("swagger", "swagger-internal");
});
```

which does provide me with two separate documents, and two separate UIs. However, despite their differing routes, they share the functionality, fully.

I found [this issue](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/1713) that barely has enough information to direct me to a deleted file from the repo and [this documentation](https://github.com/RSuter/NSwag/wiki/Document-Processors-and-Operation-Processors#operation-processors) that's of minuscule if any help at all.

I know that I can write some filter or something (how, though, that's anybody's guess) and use this bit of code:

```cs
services.AddOpenApiDocument(settings =>
{
    // the settings here in particular
});
```

and perhaps, yet again, duplicate it or something. But this is where I'm absolutely and utterly stuck and I have no idea how to progress further. I only know that all those bits and pieces of code are glued together with magic strings, but where to apply the glue in this case, that I do not know.

I heard rumors and legends that someone somewhen knew a distant relative of somebody who managed to do that, so perhaps I'll be lucky and this person is here.

---

**Update 1:**

I did manage to hack together this bit

```cs
public class IncludeInternalApisProcessor : IOperationProcessor
{
    public bool Process(OperationProcessorContext context)
    {
        return context.ControllerType.FullName?.ToUpper().Contains("ADMIN") ?? false;
    }
}
```

and

```cs
services.AddOpenApiDocument(settings =>
{
    settings.SchemaNameGenerator = new NSwagNestedNameGenerator();
});
services.AddOpenApiDocument(settings =>
{
    settings.DocumentName = "internal";
    settings.OperationProcessors.Add(new IncludeInternalApisProcessor());
    settings.SchemaNameGenerator = new NSwagNestedNameGenerator();
});
```

but now I feel filthy having done that. And I lose out on versioning.